# Which is the correct way to persist Firebase Session after cookie expires?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, refresh-token

I've been dealing with authentication, reading and watching videos about it. I came up building my own JWT solution, based on an access_token who expires after five minutes, and a refresh_token that never expires. I stored that tokens in cookies and I use the second one to provide more access_tokens when needed. I store the refresh_token in Redis, to be able to revoke if one of those is leaked / stolen.

Nowadays, I need to move my auth system to Google Firebase in order to store my users there, and to add the Google and Facebook login as well. But I found that I need to create a sessionCookie that expires in, as much, two weeks. After that, the user is signed-out from the app and it needs to access again manually. I want to refresh that firebase sessionCookie in the correct way (automatically, server-side), but the docs say nothing about it. I came up doing my own solution again, but I believe it is not right.

I don't want to use the **getIdToken** method because, with that thing of custom tokens, I need to modify each of my api calls in the client side, and that's not the idea. I want to do the refresh at server-side.

**So, which is the correct way to refresh the sessionCookie automatically and to keep the user authenticated permanently?**

Info that I read here:

- [How to Refresh Firebase Session Cookie (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684631/how-to-refresh-firebase-session-cookie)
- [How to extend Firebase Session Cookie Beyond 2 weeks? (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970700/how-to-extend-firebase-session-cookies-beyond-2-weeks)
- [Refresh Tokens (by Auth0)](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens)
- [JWT Auth with Node.js (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbsmsi7l3r4)
- [Server-side Firebase Authentication Using Express JS (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX8by4eCyG4)
- And, of course, the official docs from Google Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Firebase ID tokens expire in an hour, this default behavior cannot be modified or changed with the exception of admin sdk created custom tokens where you have a near unlimited range for expiration.

once this token is generated from your backend or cloud function, you can authenticate your client with this custom token and have it available on the next session.

the only issue would be your apps local cache settings which can be wiped, clearing your refresh token and preventing your user from re-authenticating.

From the Admin SDK documentation with custom auth, these 3 topics are of interest.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

Comment: Firebase ID tokens expire in 1 hour. Firebase session cookies have custom expiration times ranging from 5 minutes to 2 weeks. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: thanks for the ping, this answer was from a while ago and was in need of cleanup